# How Do I Use a Variable in new[]'s Value Initialization

Tags: c++, variables, c++11, new-operator, initializer-list

So when `new`ing an array of `char`s I can value initialize:

```
const char* foo = new char[4]{'J', 'o', 'n', '\0'};
```

**What I want to know is how to use a variable in that `initializer_list`:**

```
const string initializer{"jon"};
const char* foo = new char[4]{initializer.c_str()}; // This doesn't work, can I make it work?
```

Comment: A quick comment here, *I know* that in C++11 I should use auto pointers or `string`s. I'm trying to understand how `new` value initialization works conceptually, *not* use it in my code.

Comment: `const char* foo = new char[4]{initializer[0], initializer[1], initializer[2], initializer[3]};` if you really insist. Or simply allocate, then `strcpy` (or `std::copy` or similar).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I suppose that does answer the question :J I was hoping for something a little less explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variable, but you can't use a string and expect the compiler to magically split it up.

```
const char* ip = initializer.c_str();
const char* foo = new char[4]{ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]};
```

Once you have a variable length, though, this doesn't work at all. You just have to allocate and then use `string::copy` to fill the array in a separate step.